# How to get WooCommerce product category name to display on front page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a few products per product category on front page. I am able to show the products but can't get the product category name displayed using the slug.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, This worked :

```
<?php 
    $product_cat_name = get_term_by( 'slug', 'slugname', 'product_cat' );
    echo $product_cat_name->name;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find product category using this code...
I have also added code to get woocommerce category image

```
  $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC'));
    foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : ?>
    <?php $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/product-category/<?php echo $catTerm->slug; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></a>
         <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/product-category/<?php echo $catTerm->slug; ?>">  <h2><img src="<?php echo $a['url']; ?>"> 
           <?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></h2></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I need something specific, I need to get the product category name using product category slug. Something like get_cat_name()